# Can a Map of data be passed as a parameter in go_router?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigation, flutter-go-router

I want to pass a map of complex data as a parameter to a `GoRoute()`.  However, from what I can see, the param is a `String`.  I tried converting my Map -> String, but it immediately causes all sorts of errors due to format errors: `Unexpected character (at character 2)`.

Im most likely going about this the incorrect way.

Is it even possible to send a `Map` of data as a parameter in GoRouter?

Comment: if your `Map` can't be converted to `String`, why don't you try to fix it? is it still usable even you can pass `Map` as parameter. because your `Map` is not the correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, but JsonEncode and then JsonDecode on the other side, I have performed it incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `Model` and have `toJson()` `fromJson()` methods. And pass between routes as `Model` using `extra`.

---

#### Example:

**Object:**

```
class Sample {
  String attributeA;
  String attributeB;
  bool boolValue;
  Sample(
      {required this.attributeA,
      required this.attributeB,
      required this.boolValue});}
```

**Define GoRoute as**

```
 GoRoute(
    path: '/sample',
    name: 'sample',
    builder: (context, state) {
      Sample sample = state.extra as Sample; // -> casting is important
      return GoToScreen(object: sample);
    },
  ),
```

**Call it as:**

```
Sample sample = Sample(attributeA: "True",attributeB: "False",boolValue: false)
context.goNamed("sample",extra:sample );
```

**Receive it as:**

```
class GoToScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Sample? object;
  GoToScreen({super.key, this.object});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Text(
        object.toString(),
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```